# /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory No package glibc.i386 available

Tags: linux

I am trying to install the weblogic server on Linux, I am getting below error not able install the weblogic software and not able install the "glibc.i386"

[root@localhost weblogic]# uname -a

Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@localhost weblogic]# ./wls1036_linux32.bin
bash: ./wls1036_linux32.bin: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

[root@localhost weblogic]# yum install glibc.i686
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package glibc.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost weblogic]# yum install glibc.i386
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package glibc.i386 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Let me know how to download the required packages and how to install the packages.
what is the exact command's

Comment: have you tried not specifying explicitly the architecture? ("sudo yum install glibc")

Comment: Have you tried paying for a RHN subscription?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running a 64bit OS since your Kernel version says  `2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64`. x86_64 means 64 bit. The error from Weblogic Server installer is because it is trying to use i386 (which is 32 bit) executables. Try to install a 64 bit version of  Weblogic Server. You'll likely find it on the Oracle site and the download file will probably be `wls1036_linux64.bin` instead of `wls1036_linux32.bin`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, "wls1036_linux32.bin" in this "32" means 32 bit JVM, Please let me know how to download the packages to linux and how to install the packages